How can I dynamically change SelectableDates in DateRangePicker
I have a DateRangePickerState initialized with an initial set of selectable dates. I want to update the selectable dates whenever the user selects a new start date in the DateRangePicker. Specifically, I want to adjust the selectable dates based on the selected start date (4months from the startDate).
I've thought about using a LaunchedEffect to trigger a side effect when the start date is changed, and inside this effect, I update the selectable dates. However, I'm unsure about the correct approach to update the selectable dates in the DateRangePickerState.
val datePickerState = rememberDateRangePickerState(
    selectableDates = object: SelectableDates {
        override fun isSelectableDate(utcTimeMillis: Long): Boolean {
            return utcTimeMillis in getMinimumDate()..getMaximumDate()
        }
    }
)

LaunchedEffect(datePickerState.selectedStartDateMillis) {
    // could not update the selectableDates since it is Val
}

DateRangePicker(state = datePickerState)


As it is right now, there is no way to do this.
This is now possible, see my other answer.
I find it a valid use case to also restrict the selectable end dates, but that's not supported by the DateRangePicker.
As you already figured out you cannot change the selectableDates after the state object was created. Even if you would create your own SelectableDates implementation that would dynamically calculate the allowed days by taking the selectedStartDateMillis into account, this wouldn't help because you cannot control how this function is called. As it is currently implemented, the function is only called when a new month is scrolled into view, but you would also need it to be executed when the start date is selected.
Until there is built-in support to specify the selectable end dates the only option would be to switch out the entire DateRangePickerState object when it comes to the user selecting the end date. Then you could provide a different selectableDates parameter where the calculation is based on the selectedStartDateMillis of the first state object. That seems a bit drastic (and it is), but it would get the job done.

Edit 2024-11-28: The following bug is fixed in Compose BOM 2024.10.01 (library androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.1)
Sadly, this currently won't work either because of a bug (at least up until the current version as of writing, 1.3.0-alpha06) that prevents the UI to update properly when the DateRangePicker's state parameter is changed. Until this is fixed (I'm not sure if that bug is even known to the developers) you can only try to address an invalid date selection after the fact, you cannot prevent it from happening in the first place.

You can always check afterwards if the selected end date lies in the allowed range:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun validateSelectedRange(state: DateRangePickerState, datePeriod: DatePeriod): Boolean =
    state.selectedStartDateMillis?.let { startDate ->
        state.selectedEndDateMillis?.let { endDate ->
            val maxEndDate = Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(startDate)
                .toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.UTC).date
                .plus(datePeriod)
                .atStartOfDayIn(TimeZone.UTC)
                .toEpochMilliseconds()

            endDate <= maxEndDate
        }
    } ?: true

With that you can, for example, highlight the invalid range selection and prevent further processing until fixed. When you use a material theme you could switch to error colors with something like this:
val datePickerState = rememberDateRangePickerState()

val isError = !validateSelectedRange(datePickerState, DatePeriod(months = 4))

val colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors().let {
    if (isError) it.copy(
        selectedDayContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.errorContainer,
        selectedDayContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
        dayInSelectionRangeContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.errorContainer,
        dayInSelectionRangeContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
    )
    else it
}

DateRangePicker(
    state = datePickerState,
    colors = colors,
) 


This is very sad

Not any more, see my edit. :)

Although not natively supported, from Material 3 version 1.3.1 (Compose BOM 2024.10.01) onwards this can now be achieved with a helper function.
The idea is to supply two different SelectableDates to the DateRangePickerState: One that is used to select the start date and another for the selection of the end date. The latter can access the currently selected start date so you can perform date arithmetics, like adding four months:
val state: DateRangePickerState = rememberDateRangePickerState(
    selectableStartDates = DatePickerDefaults.AllDates,
    selectableEndDates = object : SelectableEndDates {
        override fun isSelectableDate(utcTimeMillis: Long, startDate: Long): Boolean =
            utcTimeMillis in startDate..startDate + DatePeriod(months = 4)
    },
)

DateRangePicker(state)

With this for the date arithmetics:
operator fun Long.plus(datePeriod: DatePeriod) =
    Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(this)
        .toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.UTC).date
        .plus(datePeriod)
        .atStartOfDayIn(TimeZone.UTC)
        .toEpochMilliseconds()

When no start date is selected the date picker uses selectableStartDates to determine the selectable dates. Once a start date was selected the date picker switches to selectableEndDates to determine what can be selected as an end date.
All you need is an overloaded rememberDateRangePickerState and the SelectableEndDates interface:
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun rememberDateRangePickerState(
    @Suppress("AutoBoxing") initialSelectedStartDateMillis: Long? = null,
    @Suppress("AutoBoxing") initialSelectedEndDateMillis: Long? = null,
    @Suppress("AutoBoxing") initialDisplayedMonthMillis: Long? = initialSelectedStartDateMillis,
    yearRange: IntRange = DatePickerDefaults.YearRange,
    initialDisplayMode: DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker,
    selectableStartDates: SelectableDates = DatePickerDefaults.AllDates,
    selectableEndDates: SelectableEndDates,
): DateRangePickerState {
    var startDate by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(initialSelectedStartDateMillis) }
    var endDate by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(initialSelectedEndDateMillis) }

    val currentSelectableEndDates = remember(startDate, selectableStartDates, selectableEndDates) {
        startDate?.let {
            object : SelectableDates {
                override fun isSelectableDate(utcTimeMillis: Long): Boolean =
                    selectableEndDates.isSelectableDate(utcTimeMillis, it)

                override fun isSelectableYear(year: Int): Boolean =
                    selectableEndDates.isSelectableYear(year, it)
            }
        } ?: selectableStartDates
    }

    return rememberDateRangePickerState(
        initialSelectedStartDateMillis = initialSelectedStartDateMillis,
        initialSelectedEndDateMillis = initialSelectedEndDateMillis,
        initialDisplayedMonthMillis = initialDisplayedMonthMillis,
        yearRange = yearRange,
        initialDisplayMode = initialDisplayMode,
        selectableDates = if (startDate != null && endDate == null) currentSelectableEndDates
        else selectableStartDates,
    ).apply {
        startDate = selectedStartDateMillis
        endDate = selectedEndDateMillis
    }
}

interface SelectableEndDates {
    fun isSelectableDate(utcTimeMillis: Long, startDate: Long) = true
    fun isSelectableYear(year: Int, startDate: Long) = true
}

